# Curl + IMAP Не сохраняет тело письма в файл

Tags: linux, консоль, curl, ssh

возникла проблема не как не могу решить! Проблема в следующем, я подключаюсь к IMAP аккаунту в терминале с помощью Curl для получению письма по UID в терминал ответ приходит с письмом которое я запрашиваю, но вот при попытки сохранить результат в текст мне в файл сохраняет одну строку с размером письма и все. Самого письма нет! Как решить эту проблему подскажите пожалуйста.

Всем спасибо!

Запрос: `curl -v -u '*****:*****' imap://mail.mydomen.com/INBOX -X 'UID FETCH 1 BODY[]'`

Ответ: * 1 FETCH (UID 1 BODY[] {2940}

Answer (score 0):

Для того что бы результат и письмо сохранило в файл нужно в конец добавить "2>&1"

```
curl -v -u '*****:*****' imap://mail.mydomen.com/INBOX -X 'UID FETCH 1 BODY[]' 2>&1
```

Всем спасибо, ответил что бы знали ответ!